# Is there a way to make an actively updated website stream to RTMP

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp

Is there a way to make a website broadcast as RTMP?

I am streaming sports games and would like to use the scoring apps web url and add it to my stream using Switcher Studio's custom RTMP server and add it as an overlay during my stream.

here is a sample of the URL
https://gc.com/scoreboard-5c7592983549c9002181918e?g=5&p=59e7f6a0bacc5500189a61bc

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `make a website broadcast`?

Comment: so that url is a sports "ticker" that updates the score, I want to use it as an overlay in switcher studio which only takes rtmp from outside sources.  So if I could present that website as an rtmp (as if I had it on a computer with a camera looking at it) I could add it to a streaming game as a scoreboard.

Comment: So something like obs plus nginx+rtmp? That is really more superuser.com question.